# Сохранение действий во Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Всем доброго времени суток. Во фрагменте есть 3 switch. Нужно сделать так, чтобы они запомнили своё положение и при повторном заходе в приложение восстанавливали своё положение/значение. Допустим, включил switch, вышел. Зашёл в приложение и он включён. Гуглил, нужного ответа не нашёл. Если есть, то ткните пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В соответствии с долгом перед Отечеством просто обязан заметить, что плохо гуглили)

Есть такая штука, называется SharedPreferences. По сути это мапа мап с ключами типа String и значениями мапа/ваши данные. Идеально решит вашу задачу. Не стану копировать кэпские примеры, посмотрите сами [тут](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences), [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php) ну или еще где-нибудь =)